# Creating a Button in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am fairly new to programming as I am only in a Computer Science class in high school. I have thought of the idea of creating a chess program that basically simulates a game of chess. To do this I figured I would have the users click on the spot that they would want to move to.

I have looked all over the internet, including java's API's, and I have found some very useful information. After all of this however, I am still very confused about all of the different methods and classes as well as interfaces to use to create and use Buttons in Java. Although this isn't a question about code(Sorry), I was wondering if anybody knew of any tutorials that would be suitable for my situation.  All I am looking for is something that can show me how to create and use a simple, one function button. Preferably, it would be nice if it describes all of the methods so that I actually understand what I am doing.

Again, sorry this isnt a question about code. I couldn't think of a better place to ask this question, than Stack Overflow so please do not down-vote this "question".

Thanks

Comment: Read the Java documentation. It explains the methods.

Comment: "I couldn't think of a better place" isn't reason enough to ignore the rules and purpose of Stack Overflow when it comes to whether this question is suitable for SO or not. Not all good SO questions have code, but this question is broad and will likely elicit opinionated answers.

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jbutton/handle-action-events-for-jbutton/)

Comment: You should try a Java Swing tutorial [like this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/), which will show you more on how to create a GUI.

Comment: I'm sorry @ajp15243 for "not following the rules" if I did so by asking a programming question on a programming website. If you would like to refer me to another website that is appropriate to ask such a "rule-breaking" question, please do so. It doesn't seem to be bothering anybody else since I have already received very helpful links.

Comment: @user3164008 I am not trying to be antagonistic, I am trying to be helpful, so I would appreciate it if we could keep this civil. If people are posting answers, then it is because they either don't understand SO rules themselves or are doing it out of the good of their hearts, something I would not deny them even if I could. However, do realize that SO was built with a specific goal and procedure in mind, and there are guidelines for how to achieve that. Flagging, downvoting, etc. are generally used as a crowdsourced means to enforce those, so you won't always see strict enforcement of them.

Comment: I agree with @ajp15243 on this one (and if down voting causes you delete your question, on balance I think that is better for SO).  The members of this site are motivated by many things to answer questions (no mater how bad they are presented), but for SO to be it's most helpful it should only be populated with questions that illustrate demonstrable problems that yield objective answers.  Questions that are too broad aren't likely to be helpful to others (it's ok to post many questions about different aspects of a problem).

Comment: Questions about overall understanding of a concept can be tricky, I tried to provide as detailed an answer as I could.  In Java's case people getting started with UIs should really stick to Swing (or JavaFX), so a commonly excepted answer (I think) is possible.  I could be wrong though.  If the question was "How to create a button in C++" then I would admit there are just to many ways to accomplish this to make a discussion meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a totally self contained example (with some code comments to help you understand what is going on):

```
//Here I am using Swing and AWT (a rather standard way to manage UI elements in Java though technically not the only way)
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//Here is a base class that extends JFrame, JFrames are containers for Swing UI widgets that are represented as windows when executed
public class ButtonExample extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creatign the frame
    ButtonExample frame = new ButtonExample();
    //Creating the button with the label "Click me!"
    JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
    //Adding an action listener so we can assign some logic to be executed when this button is clicked on (this is using an anonymous inner class in future versions of Java this will be replaced by the MUCH cleaner Lamba approach, keep an eye out for that)
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      //Keep a variable to store how many times the button is clicked.  This shows that the action listener stays running in between clicks)
      private int count = 0;
      //While technically optional thew @Override annotation helps if you update interfaces, get into the habit of doing this to make future work easier, things like Eclipse will insert it for you
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Bump up the count variable
        this.count++;
        //And print it to System.out
        System.out.println("Pressed "+this.count + " times");
      }
    });
    //Add the button (with it's listener) to the frame
    frame.add(button);
    //Tell Swing to resize the frame to fit the requested size of all of it's contained widgets
    frame.pack();
    //Tell Swing to show the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //Do what you like here after button is clicked, for example:
        System.out.println("Button clicked");
    }
});

someJPanel.add(button);
```

To make such application - you will need lot's of knowledge. Also it should look nice, so lot's of work with graphics in Java..

Comment: What does the "@Override" part of the code do?

Comment: It's not that important, just leave as it is, but you can try to look at the `ActionListener` class source code also - it is very simple.

Comment: It's just annotation, means that implements this method from `java.awt.event.ActionListener`. The code will compile without it also...

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this documentation: [***Here You Are***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

There, you can download, launch the example, so you can see, try every button..